# Grails, Cucumber, Geb, and Spring Security not working together properly

Tags: grails, spring-security, geb, cucumber-jvm

I have a Grails application that is using Spring Security, and I'm trying to run tests on it with Cucumber/Geb

When I load my website with `run-app` and navigate to 'MyProject/' it redirects me to the index page (ok so far)

When I load my functional tests and navigate to 'MyProject/', it redirects me to the MyProject/login/auth page.

So my issue is, run-app in development mode works fine with Spring Security, but when I run `test-app functional:cucumber`, the site thinks I need to be logged in.

Here is my config file with my Spring Security info

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = true

grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.bcrypt.logrounds = 15
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'myproject.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'myproject.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'myproject.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "InterceptUrlMap"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
'/':                              ['permitAll'],
'/index':                         ['permitAll'],
'/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
'/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
'/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
'/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
'/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
'/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll'],
'/login/**':                          ['permitAll'],
'/logout/**':                         ['permitAll']
]
```

and my step

```
import static cucumber.api.groovy.EN.*
import pages.HomePage

Given(~/^I am on the home page$/) { ->
    to HomePage
    at HomePage
}
```

and my page

```
package pages

import geb.Page

class HomePage extends Page {
    static url = "MyProject/"

    static at = {
        title ==~ /Welcome to Grails/
    }

    static content = {

    }
}
```

With `test run-app` it seems to work fine, so I have to believe it is either in my Cucumber/Geb code or in the `test-app functional:cucumber` command somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on debug option in spring security to check what resource your tests are accessing. It looks like tests are trying to access the following: `http://localhost:8080/MyProject/MyProject` and resource '/MyProject' is not mapped in InterceptUrlMap so pessimistic locking takes place.

Try changing this

```
static url = "MyProject/"
```

to this

```
static url = "/MyProject"
```

There **is** a difference between these two. Check [Geb docs](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/browser.html#the_base_url) for more details.

BTW, but you've got an error in you Spring Security config. These two lines:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = true
```

are mutually exclusive. If resource is not mapped explicitly you might want to return 403 (first option) **or** throw an exception (second option). More details: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html